# How to make the footer positioned at the bottom of all screen sizes when you have different height pages?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, footer

I'm trying to make a sticky footer but for some reason(s) it is playing up.
I have few pages with different content height therefor when I set the footer on one of them it ruin the others.
How can I make a global style for all pages in order to have a sticky footer to the bottom of the pages and also remove any scrolling if there is not need for it as some of my pages require a scroll to reach the footer while the content is about have height.

As I test my site using a website called screen-fly to enable testing on all screen sizes I need a solution that can guarantee a responsive design on any screen size please.

My Code is available on plunker , however I researched a lot and tried some solutions for styling. Here are two of them

Solution 1 :-

```
/* **************************************************/
                      /* One solution */
    html, body {
      height:100%;
      min-height:100%;
  }
                      /*  navigation style*/
  .navbar-brand {
    margin: 0 auto;
    color:white;
  }
  .navbar-inverse {
    background: rgb(14, 78, 114);
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
    color: #8EE8CD;
  }

  /* Content style*/
  .container.content {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }

                      /*  footer style*/
  .wrapper {
      position:relative;
      min-height:100%;
  }
  footer {
      text-align: center;
      position:absolute;
      bottom:0px;
      width:100%;
      color: white;
     background-color: rgb(14, 78, 114);
  }
```

Solutoin 2:-

```
/*   Another solution */

  html, body {height: 100%;}

  #wrap {min-height: 100%;}

  #main {overflow:auto;
    padding-bottom: 150px;}  /* must be same height as the footer */

  #footer {position: relative;
    margin-top: -150px; /* negative value of footer height */
    height: 150px;
    clear:both;} 

  /*Opera Fix*/
  body:before {
    content:"";
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    width:0;
    margin-top:-32767px;
  }
```

Here are some likns of the code.

plunker Editor: [Plunker Editor](https://plnkr.co/edit/4b0WQgqmtxxEYjbLacry?p=preview)

plunker full screen: [Plunker Full Screen](https://run.plnkr.co/v60XBOD9W9Xf0rpD/)

My site on screenfly: [Screenfly Site](http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=https%3A//run.plnkr.co/v60XBOD9W9Xf0rpD/&w=320&h=480&a=33&s=1)

Comment: Have you tried `display: fixed; bottom: 0; left: 0; right: 0;` ?

Comment: change `.container.content {margin-top: 100px;}` to `.container.content {padding-top: 100px;}`

Comment: Thank you very much every one here, you really such a helpful community, however, Saurav Rastogi gave a very easy and simple answer , as I didn`t use flexbox before (will definately look at it) I wanna thank Neil Smith & SvenL too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS `calc()` function. According to your plunkr example give min-height to `.container.content` instead to giving `min-height` to `html, body, wrapper`.

Look at the updated **[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/QOEh77cSKgKQEE2kkgDB)**.

---

Logic used to give **`min-height`**:

```
.container.content {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 140px);
}
```

In the above code:

- **`vh`**: Viewport Height (`100vh` gives total screen height)
- **`140px`**: `100px` for header + `20px` for footer + `20px` for top margin of footer.

So we are just subtracting the rest of the `div`s from total viewport height.

Comment: Its my pleasure @shireefkhatab

Comment: Thank you very much Saurav, yes it is working now on any screen ,, here is the screenfly link    http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=https%3A//run.plnkr.co/Y29ftTUmFD3MnyUD/&w=1024&h=601&a=1&s=1

Comment: @shireefkhatab Fixed! Check the link in my answer again. - http://quirktools.com/screenfly/#u=https%3A//plnkr.co/QOEh77cSKgKQEE2kkgDB&w=1024&h=600&a=4&s=1

Comment: it is even nicer when u copy/  paste the full screen link only wothout the editor,, shows no scrooling at all

Comment: would you please tell me if i should follow same way if i have all margins and hieghts in percentages or ems instead of pixel .. can you give me an example please?  appreciated

Answer (score 2):

For those cases I would use **Flexbox**. This gives you the ability to completely remove your wrapper div `.wrapper`

To achieve what you want simply add the following code to your CSS

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

and change your CSS of your footer div, in your case `footer` to this

```
footer {
  margin-top: auto;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgb(14, 78, 114);
}
```

Comment: I dont know flexbox do u have a link please?

Comment: Sure. There are a lot of great articles about this topic for example [this](https://www.google.ch/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj4uPvs-fjQAhVBchQKHX6MBo0QFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2Fsnippets%2Fcss%2Fa-guide-to-flexbox%2F&usg=AFQjCNGJ7L51r6RFHr3pPfasIas-TPsiBQ) one

Answer (score 0):

Try overflow: hidden; for body.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem many people try to solve. For the longest time it required either a compromise or some hacky CSS. Thankfully with the dawn of Flexbox it is actually rather easy. Check the link below.

https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/

This page goes through solving problems like yours with Flexbox and will walk you through it.

Answer (score 0):

Change footer style

```
position: absolute;
```

to

```
position: fixed;
```

Hope that is what you wanted to achieve :)

Comment: that wouldn`t work nicely if the content is more than one page as footer will appear on the first page and keeps appearing at the bottom when u scrool but i want it to be at the end of content only.